# Get Match value from RegEx replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the following RegEx code, that finds, and replaces, the href of links. That works as intended.

But, i need to get the match value, and look it up in an array i have, to find a new value, that needs to get inserted instead, of the GUID.

This is my current code:

```
string patternLinks = @"((~\/link\.aspx\?_id=([A-Z0-9]{32})[^""]+))";
            bodyText = Regex.Replace(bodyText,
                      patternLinks,
                      "/$3/mylink.aspx");
```

"$3" is what i need to extract, do be able to use it, in my array look up.

My Array looks like this;

```
private static Dictionary<string, int> _GetNewID = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

And to get the new value, i need to do something like this, where $3 is the value, from the RegEx Replace above:

```
_GetNewID[$3]
```

How could this be done?

Comment: `Regex.Replace(bodyText, patternLinks, m => $"/{_GetNewID[m.Groups[3].Value]}/mylink.aspx")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it:

```
Regex linkRegex = new RegEx(@"((~\/link\.aspx\?_id=([A-Z0-9]{32})[^""]+))", RegexOptions.Compiled);
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
Match match = linkRegex.Match(bodyText); // Reset
int lastEnd = 0;
if (match.Success)
{
    do
    {
        string value = match.Groups[3].Value;
        string replacement = string.Format("/{0}/mylink.aspx", value);

        result.Append(bodyText.Substring(lastEnd, match.Index - lastEnd)); // Remove the match
        result.Append(replacement); // Append replacement 

        lastEnd = match.Index + match.Length;
    } while ((match = match.NextMatch()).Success);
}
result.Append(bodyText.Substring(lastEnd)); // Append tail
bodyText = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you need this:

```
bodyText = 
    Regex.Replace(
          bodyText,
          patternLinks,
          match => $"/{_GetNewID[match.Groups[3].Value].ToString()}/mylink.aspx");
```